# Implementing binomial heap

Tags: c++, binomial-heap

My aim  is to construct a binomial heap.  Here is my code which i have written right now:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void maxheapify(int a[],int length,int i)
{
    int left=2*i;
    int right=2*i+1;
    int largest=i;
    if(left<length && a[left]>a[largest])
    {
        largest=left;

    }
    if ( right<length && a[right]>a[largest])
    {
        largest=right;
    }

    if(largest!=i)
    {
int temp=a[i];
a[i]=a[largest];
a[largest]=temp;
maxheapify(a,length,largest);

    }

}
void buildmax(int a[],int length)
{
    for(int i=(length-1)/2;i>=0;i--)
    {
        maxheapify(a,length,i);

    }


}
/*void heapsort(int a[],int length)
{
    buildmax(a,length);
    for(int i=length-1;i>0;i--)
    {
        int temp=a[i];
        a[i]=a[0];
        a[0]=temp;
        maxheapify(a,i,0);


    }


}
*/
 void combine_heap(int a[],int n,int b[],int m,int c[])
 {

 }
int main()
{
    int a[100];
    int n=sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);

    int b[100];
    int m=sizeof(b)/sizeof(b[0]);
    int c[200];
    int length=sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
    for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
        a[i]=34+rand()%(length-33);
         b[i]=rand()%(i+1);
            }
    /*heapsort(a,length);*/
    /*for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
        cout<<a[i]<<"  ";*/


    return 0;
}
```

i think trivial solution would be to combine two array into third  one and then call buildmax procedure,but i think it is not efficient,i have tried to implement this pseudo code from wikipedia

```
function merge(p, q)
    while not( p.end() and q.end() )
        tree = mergeTree(p.currentTree(), q.currentTree())
        if not heap.currentTree().empty()
            tree = mergeTree(tree, heap.currentTree())
            heap.addTree(tree)
        else
            heap.addTree(tree)
        heap.next() p.next() q.next()
```

but i dont know how to implement it,because in generally  how to access subtrees?another variant is  construct  priority queue and by using insert function insert  first from one array and then from another array,but is this optimal?please help me to write code to combine these two max heap into one efficiently

Comment: We can help you debug any problems you may have, but we will not write the code for you.  We're not a code writing company.

Comment: no not write code for me,help me how to write

Comment: well, what have you written and tried?

Comment: i think what should be optimal way for combine this two max heap,and i have problem according to pseudo code,how to  access  subtrees in array?pseudo code seems to be difficult and i am searching alternative ways

Comment: Wikipedia has all the information on how to implement it efficiently - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_heap

Comment: but  pseudo code  is difficult,i need to translate it  in language

Comment: if we implement priority  queue and insert,is not it optimal?

Comment: Pseudo code is a description in human language, and that you find difficult? Seems hard to believe. That said, since you want to write C++, start with using a vector instead of raw pointers. Also, write tests, i.e. test-driven development.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good example of Binomial Heap but it is in c. You will get the basic logic to implement binomial heap. See Example [here](http://www.coders-hub.com/2013/04/c-code-for-binomial-heap-tree.html)

Or get video tutorial to [here](https://www.youtube.com/innosenblog) to understand algorithm.